# how to interpret ‘formosus’ via its morphological components

Tags: vocabulary, etymology, meaning, language-evolution, morphology

The adj. **formosus** can be decomposed as follows:

> *forma* + -os-us

where *forma* means ‘shape, form’ and *-os-* ‘with abundance’. However, when the two notions come together, the whole, which literally reads ‘with abundance of form’ does not make sense to me. Could anyone help explain how these two morphemes work together so as to bring forth the meaning ‘beautiful’?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Forma* [means](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dforma) not only "shape, form", but also "good/pleasing shape, form", i.e. "beauty". (This is a type of semantic shift called amelioration.) "Having / being abundant in beauty" = "beautiful".